# Unable to Open Postgres shell in Mac Terminal ZSH

Tags: postgresql, macos, terminal, homebrew, zsh

Disclaimer that I'm both new to Mac & Postgres. I recently got the 2020 MacBook Pro and have been setting it up for my personal [learning] development computer. In the process of attempting to install Postgres, I am having issues and am not sure what I am doing wrong / missing.

I've installed Postgres via Homebrew using:

```
brew install postgresql
```

All seems to have been installed fine, but whenever I try to open up a Postgres shell to enter commands into (coming from a Windows/Bash background), I keep getting the same response:

```
>> psql
[1] ##### killed      psql
>> psql postgres
[1] ##### killed      psql postgres
>> psql -U postgres
[1] ##### killed      psql -U postgres
```

When asking where psql is:

```
>> where psql
/opt/homebrew/bin/psql
```

When trying to make sure postgresql is launched I run as instructed in the brew installation output:

`>> pg_ctl -D /opt/homebrew/var/postgres start`

`pg_ctl: directory "/opt/homebrew/var/postgres" is not a database cluster directory`

And when attempting to check the Postgres version:

`>> postgres -V`

`[1] ##### killed      postgres -V`

I am not sure what I'm missing and any help would be appreciated! I'm trying to set up Postgres so I can use it for an Angular tutorial I'm trying to understand. The backend connection has never been my strong-suit and I'm working to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. Now there's a new version of Postgres that works (stable 13.3). Just upgrade the app via `brew upgrade`.